# python - mysql create join query with count row and one column value

Tags: python, mysql, join, count

I've been trying to solve do this query for days, but I couldn't solve it,
I would be grateful to you if you would give me some of your time and help me with this solution.

Table 1: msg

```
ID — APPID —   USER  —  Details
1  — app1  — William —  test detilas 1
2  — app2  —  David  —  test detilas 2
```

Table 2: Details

```
MSGID —  APPID —   USER   — STATUS
1     —  app1  — William  —  0
1     —  app1  — William  —  1
1     —  app1  — William  —  0
2     —  app2  —  David   —  0
```

Tables are connected by column ID, APPID and USER:

`msg.ID = Details.MSGID`

`msg.APPID = Details.APPID`

`msg.USER = Details.USER`

I need to get msg rows and Details,

Example for the result will be:

```
Row 1 =
ID : 1
APPID : app1
Details : test detilas 1
STATUS : count status values (0+0+1 = 1)
COUNTS_Rows : how many rows found in Details table (= 3 records)
```

```
Row 2 =
ID : 2
APPID : app2
Details : test detilas 2
STATUS : count status values (0)
COUNTS_Rows : how many rows found in Details table (= 1 record)
```

Comment: Why do you duplicate the `APPID` and `USER` columns in both tables? Linking by `MSGID` should be enough, the others violate normalization rules.

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables and then use `SUM()` and `COUNT()` to get the information from `details`.

```
SELECT m.*, SUM(d.status) AS status, COUNT(*) AS counts_rows
FROM msg AS m
JOIN details AS d ON d.msgid = m.id
```